# .map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to loop through an array of objects I received from an Ajax request. For some reason I am not able to use the map function even though I'm sure that my data is an array. I am just learning React and know there must be some underlying concept that I'm missing but can't figure it out.

Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Search extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
 super(props); 
 this.state = {value: '', searchVal: 'No data yet'};
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 this.search = this.search.bind(this);
} 

search() {
  var val = this.state.value;
  var x = '';
  axios.post('/names', {
    search: val
  })
  .then((response) => {
    x = response.data;
    this.setState({searchVal:x})
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });  
}

handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

render() {
 console.log(this.state.searchVal); // array of objects
 var results = this.state.searchVal;
 console.log(Array.isArray(results)) // logs true

return (
    <div>
        <label htmlFor="search">Search:</label>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search-box" value=
 {this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <button id="search" onClick={this.search}>Search</button>
        <p></p>

        <div id="search-results">
           <ul>
              {results.map( (el) => {return el.name})}  //error here ?

           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
 }
}

export default Search
```

Comment: as a side note, since you are using es6 function syntax, you can rewrite that line as {results.map(el => el.name)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't called `search()` yet. You bind `search()` to `onClick` but before that your `state.searchVal` value is `No data yet` so it not an array.

You can either call `search()` at some lifecycle method or set default value for `state.searchVal: []` at constructor

Comment: Set state.searchVal = [] and it worked like a charm. Didn't realize it was trying to iterate of "No data yet" thanks. Will mark off as answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the initialization of searchVal

```
this.state = {value: '', searchVal: []};
```

When the render() function is called the first time, searchVal is still a String ('No data yet'), not an Array, that's why map doesn't work.

Comment: Answers should be complete.